# Pycharm looks to project root rather than sources root when running unit tests

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, pycharm

I reinstalled PyCharm recently and encountering an import error with the unittests: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'src'`.

I'm running a unit test from within PyCharm using the defaults (just clicking on the run icon next to the unit test).

The unittest command line displayed in the console tells me that the `--target` argument is being passed the full path from the project root. It should be a path from the sources root. The project root contains directories that are not packages. I've confirmed in the debugger, where the exception occurs, that I can import from the sources root but not from the project root used by PyCharm.

```
/path_omitted/_jb_unittest_runner.py --target path.from.project.root.myunittest.MyClass.test_function ...
```

Details:

- When I `edit configurations` for the unittest in PyCharm the `working directory` is the correct sources root for the unit test.

Comment: While this question was slightly different than the proposed duplicate (unit tests vs. a source root question), it was the same root cause and is sufficiently similar to simply consider a duplicate. The answer is the same in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your sources directory in pycharm's file explorer and select 'mark as sources root', see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: It is marked as a sources root. I expected pycharm to stop at the first sources root that it encounters, but it seems not to.

Comment: afaik sources root roughly translates to PYTHONPATH ... you can clearly have more than one source in your PYTHONPATH (or sys.PATH)

Comment: I do have multiple source roots, but the roots of the project don't contain `__init__.py` (the project spans multiple languages), therefore you can't import from the project root, which pycharm is attempting to do. It used to work fine before the reinstall though, so it must be a configuration error somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the **content root** from the main project root to the root of my particular subproject does resolve the issue. Although it's an acceptable solution, I don't think it should be strictly necessary (this wasn't the configuration previously). I'll leave the question open for a short time in case any better answers come along.